# ProgressBar Inside DialogFragment Freezing/Not Updating

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-progressbar

I have a DialogFragment where upon clicking the save button, I was trying to show a ProgressBar while the save operation is ongoing. However I can't seem to make it work:

1. I tried the ProgressBar as showing by default, when the save operation commences I noticed it freezes, so I suspect the UI is freezing
2. When it's hidden and I try showing it when the save button is clicked, it doesn't appear at all.

I suspect it has something to do with UI thread, but I'm out of ideas. Here's my code:

```
public class EditUserPreferencesDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private DashboardActivity mDashboardActivity;

    public EditUserPreferencesDialogFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mDashboardActivity = (DashboardActivity) getActivity();

        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        // Get the layout inflater
        final LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_edit_user_preferences, null);

        //Title comes from activity
        builder.setTitle(mDashboardActivity.EditUserPreferencesTitle);

        builder.setView(view);

        final Switch displaySwitch = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.popup_change_pref_sub_group);
        final Switch pushSwitch = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.popup_change_pref_push_group);
        final ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_edit_user_pref);
        final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll_edit_user_pref);

        if (mDashboardActivity.zvUserPreferences.getDisplay().isEmpty()) {
            displaySwitch.setChecked(false);
        } else {
            displaySwitch.setChecked(true);
        }

        if (mDashboardActivity.zvUserPreferences.getPush().isEmpty()) {
            pushSwitch.setChecked(false);
        } else {
            pushSwitch.setChecked(true);
        }

        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.save, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            /**
             * This method will be invoked when a button in the dialog is clicked.
             *
             * @param dialog The dialog that received the click.
             * @param which  The button that was clicked (e.g.
             *               {@link DialogInterface#BUTTON1}) or the position
             */
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progress.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        });
                        ll.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                ll.setEnabled(false);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).start();

                boolean hasChanged = false;

                //save sub and push
                UserSub userSub = UserSubSingleton.findUserSub(mDashboardActivity.zvUserPreferences
                        .getUserId(), mDashboardActivity.zvUserPreferences.getChild());

                String display = displaySwitch.isChecked() ? "X" : "";
                String push = pushSwitch.isChecked() ? "X" : "";

                if (!userSub.getDisplay().equals(display)) {
                    userSub.setDisplay(display);
                    hasChanged = true;
                }
                if (!userSub.getPush().equals(push)) {
                    userSub.setPush(push);
                    hasChanged = true;
                }
                if (hasChanged) {

                    try {
                        UserSubSingleton.updateUserSub(userSub);
                        //refresh user preferences data
                        mDashboardActivity.userPrefGroup.clear();
                        mDashboardActivity.userPrefChild.clear();
                        //refresh user pref singletons
                        ZvUserPreferencesSingleton.initialize(getActivity());
                        UserSubSingleton.initialize(getActivity());
                        mDashboardActivity.onUserPrefDisplay(
                                mDashboardActivity.userPrefUser,
                                mDashboardActivity.userPrefChild,
                                mDashboardActivity.userPrefGroup,
                                mDashboardActivity.userPrefExpListView,
                                mDashboardActivity.userPrefProfileCode);

                        //Show pop-up message
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.preferences_saved, Toast
                                .LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (OnlineODataStoreException e) {
                        //refresh user preferences data
                        mDashboardActivity.userPrefGroup.clear();
                        mDashboardActivity.userPrefChild.clear();
                        //refresh user pref singletons
                        ZvUserPreferencesSingleton.initialize(getActivity());
                        UserSubSingleton.initialize(getActivity());
                        mDashboardActivity.onUserPrefDisplay(
                                mDashboardActivity.userPrefUser,
                                mDashboardActivity.userPrefChild,
                                mDashboardActivity.userPrefGroup,
                                mDashboardActivity.userPrefExpListView,
                                mDashboardActivity.userPrefProfileCode);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.preferences_error, Toast
                                .LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Thanks!